# direct sum of orthogonal closed linear subspaces in an incomplete inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be an incomplete inner product space. Is it true that X always contains at least two (may be more than two) orthogonal closed linear subspaces such that their sum is not closed in X. If it is true than how to prove and if it is false than how can we find a counter example. Thanks for any help.